# How to draw XNA window inside a panel?

Tags: vb.net, xna

I'm developing a 3d Viewer in vb.net and xna. It's working very well.
I have now a windows form and an xna render window, but I would like to render it inside a panel in the windows form.
I have searched for info, but it's so hard to adapt it into my application.
How can I do it?

[alt text http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/384/87117064.jpg](http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/384/87117064.jpg)

[Here is the application.](http://www.elenigmadelaabadia.com/david/visor3D_v2.1.rar)

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you should keep it separate. It is so much easier because you don't have to worry about managing the graphics device. However if you must know, you can find the winforms series on the [xna creator's club](http://creators.xna.com) site. it shows you how to render to a winforms panel

1. http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series1
2. http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series2